# Using JavaScript and cartodb.js to get layer's total amount of visible data in certain moment?

Tags: carto, carto-js, torque

I am working with a torque layer and I would like to know for each moment the amount of data points shown in the visualization.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try with something like this (not tested):

```
var sql = new cartodb.SQL({user: 'YOUR_USER'});

torqueLayer.on('change:time', function(changes) {
  if(changes.time && !isNaN( changes.time.getTime() )){

    tt = changes.time;

    sql.execute("SELECT count(*) as n FROM YOUR_TORQUE_TABLE WHERE YOUR_DATE_FIELD < to_timestamp ("+tt.getTime()+"/1000)")

    .done(function(data) {
        if (data.rows && data.rows.length) {
            n_points = parseInt(data.rows[0].n);
            console.log("There are " + n_points + " points loaded");
        }
    })
});
```